# mongodb conditional query greater than $gt returns zero results

Tags: mongodb, jax-rs, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb database which has a users collection containing the following document

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5161446e03642eab4a818fcd"),
  "id": "35",
  "userInfo": {
  "name": "xyz",
  "rollNumber": 121
   }
}
```

I want to get all the rows whose id is greater than a specific value

```
@GET
@Path("/query")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
 public List<String> getLactionInfo(@QueryParam("from") int from) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    // check if ids greater than 0
    query.put("id", new BasicDBObject("$gt", from));
    // get the collection of users
    DBCursor cursor = getTable("users").find(query);
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject object = cursor.next();
        String id = cursor.next().get("_id").toString();
        object.put("_id", id);
        String objectToString = object.toString();
        listUsers.add(objectToString);

    }

    return listUsers;
}
```

When I debugged my code its showing that the listUsers is null.Also when I manually run the following query in the console I get no results.

```
db.users.find({id:{$gt:60}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` in your sample data is stored as a `string`. So, the `$gt` check is trying to compare an `integer` to a `string`.

If you switch your `id` value to an `integer`, it should work as expected.

For example:

```
db.test.insert( { "id": 40, "name": "wired" } )
db.test.insert( { "id": 60, "name": "prairie" } )
db.test.insert( { "id": 70, "name": "stack" } )
db.test.insert( { "id": 80, "name": "overflow" } )
db.test.insert( { "id": "90", "name": "missing" } )
```

Then, the test:

```
> db.test.find({"id": { "$gt": 60 }}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("516abfdf8e7f7f35107081cc"),
        "id" : 70,
        "name" : "stack"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("516abfe08e7f7f35107081cd"),
        "id" : 80,
        "name" : "overflow"
}
```

For a quick data fix up you could do something like this from the shell (paste as one line and change `myCollection` to your collection name:

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(function(doc) { doc.id = parseInt(doc.id, 10); 
     db.test.save(doc); })
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help it was really stupid of me to miss on something that trivial.